# How to initialize two back slashes as one character in C

Tags: c

```
if (ch == '\\')
{
    escape_ch = '\\\\';
}
```

The compiler is not happy with 4 backslashes but I need to be able to make `'\\'` as one character. C reads `'\\'` as one backslash. So I tried `'\\\\'` as two backslashes and it's not working. I need this in order to implement my program.

Comment: Two backslashes make 2 characters..

Comment: The first '\' in C is an "escape", the second yields the desirec character '\' which is one character. If you want two backslashes in the output, you'll need 2 characters

Comment: actually, I think stack overflow editted my previous comment. Where it says "... able to make '\' as one character...", I actually wrote "... able to make '\\' as one character..." and where it says "... I tried '\\" as two backslashes...", I actually wrote "... I tried '\\\\" as two backslashes..."

Comment: I also cannot make this into a character array. My program wants me to make it into one character. for example, I am allowed to make '\t' and '\n' one character

Comment: @user1363410 You need to tell us what you actually need so we can help you.

Comment: Hi I'm sorry. Basically, I'm having trouble tokenizing this string. "abc\\def" with this tokenizer string "\\". Not allowed to use strtok. My output has to be "abc" "def"

Comment: '\\' requires one character to be stored. '\\\\' = '\\' +'\\' i.e. 2 characters required. Cannot be stored in one character. what is it that you are trying to achieve...

Comment: @user1363410 I fixed your question by using SO's code quotes. Others: What the OP wants is clear from their other comments below. See my answer, which is guaranteed correct.

Comment: `'\\\\'` is a multi-character literal; its value is implementation-defined, and it's almost certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting confused and don't really have the problem that you think you have. When you see a backslash, you check for 'n' and replace it with '\n', right? That is, '\' + 'n' -> '\n'. Well, just do the same for the backslash, but replace it with itself: '\' + '\' -> '\'.

```
c = getchar();
if (c == '\\') /* escape */
{
    c = getchar();
    switch( c ):
    {
        case 'n':
            c = '\n';
            break;
        case 't':
            c = '\t';
            break;
        case '\\':
            c = '\\'; /* not even necessary */
            break;
        ...
    }
}
/* store c in buffer */
```

And by omitting that unnecessary assignment, you can combine the processing of the characters that map to themselves:

```
    switch( c ):
    {
        case 'n':
            c = '\n';
            break;
        case 't':
            c = '\t';
            break;
        case '\\': case '"': case '\'':
            /* these escaped chars map to themselves so don't change c */
            break;
        /* ... handle other escapes such as \r, \<octal digits> too */
        case EOF:
            error("premature end of file in escape sequence"); /*write a function, error, that prints a message and a newline on stderr and calls exit(1) */
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A character in C can only be one character, therefore you can't put two backslashes in. If you explain what you want we might be able to better help you.

You can do tokenization using strstr by doing:

```
tok1 = str;
tok2 = strstr(str, "\\\\");
*tok2 = '\0';
tok2 += 2;
```

Comment: Ok. because I'm able to do

if (ch == 'n')
{
 escape_ch = '\n';
}

and my compiler doesn't complain

Comment: @user1363410 Yes, because \n represents the newline character. Numerically it's character number 10.

Comment: I'm trying to tokenize this string. "abc\\def" with this tokenizer string "\\". Not allowed to use strtok. My output has to be "abc" "def"

Comment: I'm allowed to use any other string manipulation that doesn't involve functions that perform tokenization processes such as stkrsep or strtok

Comment: I was copying each character from the original string into another character array, and i would combine escape characters such as \n or \t as one character. I'm just having trouble with \\

Comment: ' I'm able to do `if (ch == 'n') { escape_ch = '\n'; }` ' -- sure, because both `'n'` and `'\n'` are one character. 'I'm just having trouble with \\ ' -- I think you may just think you are. :-) Do it exactly the same way; after you see the first backslash, look to see if the next char is a backslash. If so, copy a backslash to the output. Voila, "\\\\" has been reduced to a single character.

Comment: @user1363410 ' i would combine escape characters such as \n or \t as one character. I'm just having trouble with \\ ' -- See my answer!

Answer (score -1):

Here is solution without strtok:

```
    for(i=0, j=0, k=-1; i < strlen(str); i++){
        if(str[i] == '\\') j++;
        else j=0;
        if(j == 2){
            printf("%d %d\n", k + 1, i - 2);
            k = i;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", k + 1, i - 1);
```

It'll give you indexes, and then you'll be able to print it or `strncpy()` to another string.

Comment: That code is incomprehensible and doesn't work (consider the treatment of more than 2 consecutive backslashes ... you don't reset j properly), and strncpy is very rarely what you want.